# Azure AD user creation source

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, provisioning

How do you find out the source of the user creation in Azure AD, for example, if the user was created via an HR cloud solution? We're using powershell and need to implement some changes to users that were created by the HR solution and not the users created directly on Azure AD. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) of your Azure Active Directory

Comment: Thanks jesús-hernández Do you know of a powershell command to access this information?

Comment: Try with this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditdirectorylogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#example-2--get-audit-logs-initiated-by-a-user-or-application

Comment: Thanks jesús-hernández, unfortunately the Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs cmd is in the AzureADPreview module, which I cannot install on the Ubuntu machine stood up by Azure Cloud Shell which I'm using.